# Does Math.Net have a LogSumExp method?

Tags: c#, .net, math, numeric, math.net

I'm new to [Math.NET Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) and I'm looking for an implementation of [LogSumExp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp), is there an existing function for that?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be missing, you can try the following method:

```
double LogSumExp(params double[] x) => Math.Log(x.Select(xVal => Math.Exp(xVal)).Sum());
```

Comment: that's a very concise implementation, but usually [this trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp#A_strictly_convex_log-sum-exp_type_function) should be used for numerical stability

Comment: another extension method with Kahan Sum should solve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2456422/1099716